# In couchbase 2.0.2, how can I get all revs of a document

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

When I using Couchdb, document can be have many revs, and I can fetch all revs from http api

But when I using Couchbase, I'm try using: rev=1-000000000000000, revs=true, revs_info=true

It's allways doesn't display any previus rev

It's another params to fetch?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information? It's not part of the public API. CouchBase and CouchDB are intentionally different ([reference](http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are mixing features from Couchbase and Couchdb.

Couchbase has a "rev" metada that is an internal attribute used for Cross Data Center Replication (XDCR). Couchbase 2.0 does not store multiple revisions of a document. You have only 1 version of the document.

This notion of revision is only used in Couchdb product.